# Generating phrase permutations

Tags: java, algorithm, generator, permutation

I have an interesting problem that I can't - for the life of me - figure out a good solution for. I will be given a phrase that has 0+ "tokens" in it. For instance:

> How now %A1% cow. The %A2% had oddly-shaped %A3%.

Above, `%A1%`, `%A2%` and `%A3%` are all "tokens". Each token will have its own respective list of possible words that could be used in lieu of it:

```
public class Token {
    // Ex: %A1%
    private String code;

    // Ex: "brown", "red", "silly"
    private List<String> candidates;
}
```

I need to write some code that will take any arbitrary phrase (not just the example above) and scan it for the existence of tokens. If tokens are found, then I need it to generate every permutation of the phrase using every combination of each token's candidate list. For instance, if the following candidates existed for the 3 tokens above:

```
%A1%
====
brown
red
silly

%A2%
====
arsonist
banker

%A3%
====
feet
hands
```

Then the following sentence permutations would be generated:

```
How now brown cow. The arsonist had oddly-shaped feet.
How now brown cow. The arsonist had oddly-shaped hands.
How now brown cow. The banker had oddly-shaped feet.
How now brown cow. The banker had oddly-shaped hands.
How now red cow. The arsonist had oddly-shaped feet.
How now red cow. The arsonist had oddly-shaped hands.
How now red cow. The banker had oddly-shaped feet.
How now red cow. The banker had oddly-shaped hands.
How now silly cow. The arsonist had oddly-shaped feet.
How now silly cow. The arsonist had oddly-shaped hands.
How now silly cow. The banker had oddly-shaped feet.
How now silly cow. The banker had oddly-shaped hands.
```

Since `%A1%` has 3 possible values, and both `%A2%` and `%A3%` have 2 possible values each, we have a total of 3 x 2 x 2 = 12 permutations.

If we always had a fixed number of tokens in the phrase, the problem is a lot easier (at least to me). But the problem is:

1. We're not sure how many tokens the phrase will contain (it might even contain 0 tokens); and
2. We don't know what tokens (and thus which candidate lists) will appear in each phrase, so we need to scan the phrase and obtain a list of tokens, and then be able to dynamically plop them in to the "permutation generator" as needed.

For some reason I am not able to wrap my brain around this one. Any ideas for how I could code this up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this question is off topic for the site please explain to me how and I'll happily delete it myself. But please just don't downvote/closevote as that will not teach me anything or help me phrase better questions in the future.

Comment: Or perhaps this question is a better fit for a different SE site, like Progammers?

Comment: You're getting close-votes because the question is long but you haven't shown any code, and people are quick to jump on that in the review queues :-\ If I were you, I'd strip the question down to the single part you're having trouble with--in this case, it sounds like you're having trouble with using the replacement Map to generate all the permutations, so maybe start there. The more specific you can make the question, the better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to get all the permutations. Something like this pseudocode:

```
void applyAllTokens(string s, stack<string> token_names) {
     if (token_names.isEmpty()) { 
         print(s);
         return;
     }
     top_name = token_names.pop();
     foreach (string token_value in map[top_name]) {
         string t = replaceToken(s,top_name,token_value);
         applyAllTokens(t,token_names.copy());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You scan the phrase and get a `List` of L tokens TokenList. Each element of the list is mapped to a `List` of candidates for that token, TokenList[i] with i in [0,L):

```
TokenList[0] = [ Cow, Fox, Dog ]
TokenList[1] = [ Rapist, Arsonist, Murderer, Rapist ]
TokenList[2] = [ Feet, Shoulders, Knees, Toes ]
...
```

Now you need a function that will take a list of instances of candidates - e.g. [ Cow, Arsonist, Feet ] - and a phrase with that number of tokens, and replace the tokens.

Your problem becomes now how to generate all instance-lists from the List of Lists. This you can do recursively, as explained in another answer.

For numbers less than the maximum integer value on your platform, you can do this iteratively. First calculate the number of the iterations: it will be the product of the sizes of all the L lists, N.

Now,

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    R = i
    Tokens = [ ]
    for (j = 0; j < L; j++) {
        Tokens[j] = TokenList[ R % TokenList[j].length ]
        R /= TokenList[j].length
    }
    generateSentence(template, Tokens)
}
```

will generate all combinations in order.

Answer (score -1):

Just a rough outline before I head home for the day...

Assuming your input phrases won't contain `%` except for token use, you can just use `split()` on the `%` symbol. The resulting array will alternate between tokens and non-tokens. This way you can easily count how many tokens are present.

Then you need some way to check which ones are tokens. If they're all of the form `A#`, this should be pretty easy. Check the first one(`0`). If it's a token, all your even elements are tokens also. If it's not, the odd ones are tokens.

Store the indices for each token in a separate structure, maybe a `Map` with the token name as key and array indice as value.

Once you have the list of permutations, you can join the phrases together again in a fresh String array for each one. Copy over the non-token pieces, and then check your mapped indices to see where token `A1` goes, for instance.

Comment: Thanks @Geobits (+1) - I think my main mental blocker is in the last part: once I have the `Map<String,List<String>` (where the key might be "A1" and the value for "A1" might be a list of "brown", "red" and "silly), how do I generate all the permutations from that map? It's actually not so straight-forward, because there isn't an easy way to know what is the next token to change and which tokens should hold constant from the last iteration. Ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry but I have to -1 this as you don't mention the crucial ingredient to solving this problem: recursion.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The way I read the problem, generating permutations wasn't the issue. He even said that if the token list was fixed, he could generate permutations from that. The numbered "problems" in the OP are: 1) scanning to see if tokens are present and 2) generating a list of them to feed to the token generator. Now that he's responded, I see the question just isn't stated as clearly as it should have been.